# How to disable a zsh special variable (bang tilde !~)?

Tags: zsh

My zsh is replacing `!~` with a command I previously ran. This is a problem because when I run `awk '$1 !~ /abc/`, it replaces the `!~` with the command.

Any idea on how to disable this? It's possible it's not zsh's fault, but after googling for an hour and not finding anything I decided it was the most likely candidate.

UPDATE:

This only happens when `!~` occurs on a newline:

```
echo !~
# ~/bin/test_translate.rb

echo foo | awk '
$1 !~ /abc/'

awk: cmd. line:2:     $1 ~/bin/test_translate.rb /abc/
awk: cmd. line:2:                            ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:     $1 ~/bin/test_translate.rb /abc/
awk: cmd. line:3:                                     ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

UPDATE 2:

I've narrowed it down to this line in my `.zshrc`:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

I would like to find out what option is making `zsh` replace `!~` plus spacebar into the last path I accessed, but I don't want to stop using oh-my-zsh. I haven't manually modified `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

Comment: Weird, `echo foo | awk '$1 !~ /abc/'` works for me, without zsh substituting `!~` with a command. After all, it's protected inside quotes.

Comment: Put a backslash at the end of the  line to escape the newline character

Comment: @hd1 I tried. It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Your line worked for me... `echo foo | awk '\<newline> $1 !~ /abc/' -- comments don't allow newlines

Comment: This line works fine for me. You should test in a fresh shell: run `zsh -f`, then the `echo foo | awk ...`. It works for me. If it works for you, your current shell has options set that break it. If it does not work, compare your version: I'm running 4.3.11 (and can test on whatever you're using if needed).

Comment: Your example still protects the `!~` inside `'...'` quotes - the quoted portion spans multiple lines, but it should be passed directly to `awk`. If you left off the first `'`, however, I'd say the shell would grab it. Have you ensured this is not what you're doing?

Comment: @simont I am not leaving off the first `'`. I updated the question to show the error I get. `~/bin/test_translate.rb` is the argument of a command I ran in the past.

Comment: @simont I ran into this issue again. I tried `zsh -f` and it worked, I've realized that it's something in oh-my-zsh that is causing the weird behavior but I still don't know what it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In zsh (and some other shells) `!` triggers the history expansion (see `man zshexpn` section "HISTORY EXPANSION"). In the case of `!~` zsh will look for the most recent command starting with `~`.

If you do not use history expansion in any way, you can just disable it by adding this to your `.zshrc`

```
setopt nobanghist
```

---

Usually history expansion is not done inside single quoted strings, so it should not affect your awk command in any way:

```
$ echo !~
~/docs
$ echo foo | awk '
$1 !~ /abc/'            
foo
```

On the other hand, inside double quotes history expansion is done and you get the mentioned error message:

```
$ echo !~
~/docs
$ echo foo | awk "
$1 !~ /abc/"   
echo foo | awk "
$1 ~/docs /abc/"
awk: cmd. line:2:  ~/docs /abc/
awk: cmd. line:2:  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:  ~/docs /abc/
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

So, if the problem can be traced to `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`, I'd guess that *Oh, my ZSH* does something to break the way zsh handles quoting.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you know of any way to modify the way zsh handles quoting?

Comment: The only thing specific to quoting I can think of is with `setopt rcquotes`. This enables to print a `'` inside a single-quoted string by writing `''`. But you could for example change the behaviour of zle (zsh command line editor) by modifing the function `zle-line-finish` to replace `'` by `"`: `zle-line-finish () { emulate -L zsh; printf '%s' ${terminfo[rmkx]}; BUFFER=${BUFFER//\'/\"} }`. But I can't imagine why one would want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

From `man zshoptions`:

> BANG_HIST (+K)  
>                 Perform textual history expansion, csh-style, treating the character `!' specially.

Putting `setopt -K` after the `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` line in your `.zshrc` should prevent it from expanding any `!~` sequences (or any other `!` sequence) in commands.